# Vue JS View layer not updating

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
$(function(){
var app = new Vue({
      el:"#app",
      data: {
        testData: globalObj
      }
    });
});


html: 

<div id="app">
  <span v-text="globalObj.value"></span>
</div>
```

`globalObj` changes depending on options selected on a different page. The data updates correctly on initial load of the app, but when I change the options on another page (which updates `globalObj`) the values are not updated in the view. I was also able to get the view to update when I implicitly set/change `globalObj.value` in the console. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Your braces and parenthesis don't match up

Comment: When you say "a different page" - do you mean a different HTML window? Javascript variables are not shared between windows.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but you should be referring to `testData`.

```
<span v-text="testData.value"></span>
```